# How do I make my ArrayList<ColorSaver> persistent in android?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have the `ArrayList`...

```
 ArrayList<ColorSaver> tempList = new ArrayList<ColorSaver>();
```

and I want it so that when the user closes the app or leaves the app, all the `ColorSaver` objects in the `ArrayList` will be there when the user reopens the app. I would prefer to use the `SharedPreferences` but I can't do that because the list is a custom object...
I have looked around and found out that I can do a serializable but I tried that and failed horribly, so if somebody could guide me through the serializable deal that would be great. Oh and where do I put the code, like in `onCreate()` in my `mainActivity` or in the `activity` that is displaying the `ArrayList`

My mainActivity class

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<ColorSaver> tempList = new ArrayList<ColorSaver>();
    private static final String TAG = "Main Activity";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    final Intent intent = new Intent();

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        final NumberPicker rednp = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.redNumberPicker1);
        final NumberPicker bluenp = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.blueNumberPicker);
        final NumberPicker greennp = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.greenNumberPicker);
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.save:
                Log.i(TAG, "Save item clicked!");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SaveActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("RedValue", rednp.getValue());
                intent.putExtra("BlueValue", bluenp.getValue());
                intent.putExtra("GreenValue", greennp.getValue());
                intent.putExtra("temparray", tempList);
                startActivity(intent);
            return true;

            case R.id.recall:
                Log.i(TAG, "Recall item clicked!");
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, RecallActivity.class);
                intent2.putExtra("temparray", tempList);
                startActivity(intent2);
            return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }//End Switch
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //ArrayList<ColorSaver> tempList = new ArrayList<ColorSaver>();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        final SurfaceView sView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);


        final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.redNumberPicker1);
        np.setMaxValue(255);
        np.setMinValue(0);

        final NumberPicker np2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.greenNumberPicker);
        np2.setMaxValue(255);
        np2.setMinValue(0);

        final NumberPicker np3 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.blueNumberPicker);
        np3.setMaxValue(255);
        np3.setMinValue(0);


        if( extras != null )
        {
            np.setValue(extras.getInt("savedRValue"));
            //np.setValue(intent.getIntExtra("savedRValue", 255));
            np2.setValue(extras.getInt("savedGValue"));
            //np2.setValue(intent.getIntExtra("savedGValue", 255));
            np3.setValue(extras.getInt("savedBValue"));
            //np3.setValue(intent.getIntExtra("savedBValue", 255));
            tempList = (ArrayList<ColorSaver>) extras.getSerializable("array");
            sView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, np.getValue(), np2.getValue(), np3.getValue()));
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just don't get it...WTF");
        }


        np.setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.
                OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) 
               {
                    int rednum, greennum, bluenum;
                    rednum = np.getValue();
                    greennum = np2.getValue();
                    bluenum = np3.getValue();


                    sView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, rednum, greennum, bluenum));

                }
            });

        //GREEN NUMBERPICKER LISTENER
        np2.setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.
                OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) 
               {
                    int rednum, greennum, bluenum;
                    rednum = np.getValue();
                    greennum = np2.getValue();
                    bluenum = np3.getValue();


                    sView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, rednum, greennum, bluenum));

                }
            });

        np3.setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.
                OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) 
               {
                    int rednum, greennum, bluenum;
                    rednum = np.getValue();
                    greennum = np2.getValue();
                    bluenum = np3.getValue();




                    sView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, rednum, greennum, bluenum));

                }
            });


    }//End onCreate()

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }//END onCreateOptionsMenu()


}//END CLASS
```

My `saveActivity`, where the user saves their color combo to the `ArrayList`...

```
    public class SaveActivity extends Activity implements Serializable {

    private static final String TAG = "Save Activity";
    public ArrayList<ColorSaver> savedColors = new ArrayList<ColorSaver>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_save);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton1);
        final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.colorNameField);
        //final Intent intent = new Intent();

        savedColors = (ArrayList<ColorSaver>) extras.getSerializable("temparray");

        //Making sure the savedColors arrayList has something in it.
        if( savedColors.isEmpty() )
        {
            ColorSaver temp = new ColorSaver("Rockies Purple", 180, 80, 255);
            savedColors.add(temp);
        }





        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

                int redcolor, greencolor, bluecolor;
                redcolor = extras.getInt("RedValue");
                greencolor = extras.getInt("GreenValue");
                bluecolor = extras.getInt("BlueValue");
                String colorName = nameField.getText().toString();

                //Build the new color and add it to the arrayList
                ColorSaver saver = new ColorSaver(colorName, redcolor, greencolor, bluecolor);
                savedColors.add(saver);
                intent1.putExtra("array", savedColors);

                Log.i(TAG, savedColors.get(savedColors.size()-1).getColorName());
                startActivity(intent1);

            }
        });

    }//END OnCreate()

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.save, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}//END CLASS
```

My `recallActivity` where the user recalls their color combos...

```
  public class RecallActivity extends SaveActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Recall Activity";
    ArrayList<ColorSaver> colorsArray = new ArrayList<ColorSaver>();
    SaveActivity sActivity = new SaveActivity();


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recall);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        final Spinner colorList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.colorsSpinner);
        Button grabButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.grabButton);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        colorsArray = (ArrayList<ColorSaver>) extras.getSerializable("temparray");

        //Load the spinner with the saved colors
        addColorNames(colorsArray);

        grabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                ColorSaver selectedItem = (ColorSaver) colorList.getSelectedItem();

                int redValue, greenValue, blueValue;
                String name;
                redValue = selectedItem.getRedValue();
                greenValue = selectedItem.getGreenValue();
                blueValue = selectedItem.getBlueValue();
                name = selectedItem.getColorName();
                intent1.putExtra("savedRValue", redValue);
                intent1.putExtra("savedGValue", greenValue);
                intent1.putExtra("savedBValue", blueValue);
                intent1.putExtra("savedName", name);
                intent1.putExtra("array", colorsArray);
                startActivity(intent1);


            }//END onClick
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.recall, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }// END onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)


    public void addColorNames(ArrayList<ColorSaver> colorsArray1)
    {
        colorsArray = colorsArray1;
        //if( !colorsArray.isEmpty() )
        //{
            Spinner colorsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.colorsSpinner);

            ArrayAdapter<ColorSaver> dataAdapter 
                = new ArrayAdapter<ColorSaver>
                (RecallActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colorsArray);

            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            colorsSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            Log.i(TAG, savedColors.get(savedColors.size() - 1).toString());
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //  Log.i(TAG, "colorsSpinner came out to be null....WTF???");

        //}

    }//End addColorNames()

}//END CLASS
```

I am greatful of any help!

Comment: If you're trying to make `ColorSaver` serializable, why did you post what seems to be all your code **except** `ColorSaver.java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Android's [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) implementation.

So, I'm just guessing on your ColorSaver class since it wasn't posted, but you would implement it the following way:

## ColorSaver.java

```
public class ColorSaver implements Parcelable {
     private String mName;
     private int    mRed;
     private int    mGreen;
     private int    mBlue;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeString(mName);
         out.writeInt(mRed);
         out.writeInt(mGreen);
         out.writeInt(mBlue);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<ColorSaver> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<ColorSaver>() {
         public ColorSaver createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new ColorSaver(in);
         }

         public ColorSaver[] newArray(int size) {
             return new ColorSaver[size];
         }
     };

     private ColorSaver(Parcel in) {
         mName  = in.readString();
         mRed   = in.readInt();
         mGreen = in.readInt();
         mBlue  = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

## MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String COLOR_SAVER_LIST = "com.example.android.ColorSaverList";
    private List<ColorSaver> colorSaverList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(COLOR_SAVER_LIST)) {
            colorSaverList = new ArrayList<ColorSaver>();
            colorSaverList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(COLOR_SAVER_LIST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(COLOR_SAVER_LIST, colorSaverList);
    }
}
```